# Setting a default value for UIStepper control

Tags: ios

This should be very simple but I am not sure why it is not working.

```
cell.stepperView.value = (int) rules.currentAutoIncreaseAmt;
```

The rules.currentAutoIncreaseAmt is a property of type id. For some reason the default value of stepper is always 100.

Comment: Why is the property of type `id` and why do you try to cast the `id` to an `int`. None of that makes any sense. What kind of object did you actually assign to the `currentAutoIncreaseAmt` property?

Comment: The rules entity is auto generated from a json file. Not sure why it is showing as an id. I cannot change the json since it is controlled by the client. How can I proceed?

Comment: Can you share your json data?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What kind of object is really assigned to the property? Is is an NSNumber, an NSString, or something else? You can try `cell.stepperView.value = [rules.currentAutoIncreaseAmt intValue];`